# Can Superpowered be used to output 5.1 or 7.1 surround sound?

Tags: tvos, superpowered

I'm experimenting with [Superpowered](https://superpowered.com/) on tvOS.  I'd like to be able to output audio to more than just two stereo channels.  Is this possible using the Superpowered SDK?

So far, what I've tried is modifying the included tvOS example as follows:

- In `ViewController.m`, where Superpowered is initialized, I changed the value for the `channels` parameter from `2` to `6`.  (This is for 5.1 surround sound, which is what the connected output device supports.)
- In `audioHandler.mm`, I added the following to `audioProcessingCallback`:

  ```
  SuperpoweredDeInterleave(stereoOutput, buffers[2], buffers[3], numberOfSamples);
  SuperpoweredDeInterleave(stereoOutput, buffers[4], buffers[5], numberOfSamples);
  ```

With these changes, I expected that the whoosh would be played through all 6 surround sound speakers, but it's only being played in the front left and right speakers.  Is there anything else that I need to do to configure Superpowered for surround sound output?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this additionally, just before [audioIO start]:

```
AVAudioSession *instance = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];  
NSLog(@"output channels: %ld", (long)instance.outputNumberOfChannels);  
NSLog(@"max channels: %ld", (long)instance.maximumOutputNumberOfChannels);  
BOOL r = [instance setPreferredOutputNumberOfChannels:instance.maximumOutputNumberOfChannels error:&error];  
NSLog(@"set preferred channels: %d error: %@", r, error);  
NSLog(@"output channels: %ld", (long)instance.outputNumberOfChannels);
```

Comment: This did end up working.  However, it only works with certain HDMI devices that can decode raw PCM, such as this item: https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=13348